# Cypress number of elements in a table

Tags: cypress

Is there an easier way to count the number of elements in a table via Cypress?
I have a 3 column table and I want to count, how many times is "India" in my table.

I tried it this way:

```
   cy.get('ag-grid-table').contains(country).its('length').as("countrylength");
        cy.get('@countrylength').then((ccc) => {
          cy.log(ccc)
           })
```

but this gives me always 1, as it finds only first element.

Then I have this solution, that may probably work:

```
let count = 0;
cy.get('ag-grid-table div.ag-row').each(($el, index, $list) => {
 
    if($el.text().includes(country))
    {  count ++;    }      
   
}
```

but can't we just find that country with one line command using `length()`?

Comment: FYI, `.contains()` returns the first, most nested matching DOM element existing in your DOM.

Answer (score 4):

You could just move the `contains()` inside the selector, it gets around the restriction of only returning the first result.

You need to merge the country variable into the selector as well, either with a string template as below, or by concatenating strings (+ operator).

```js
cy.get(`ag-grid-table  div.ag-row:contains("${country}")`)
  .its('length').as("countrylength");

cy.get('@countrylength').should('eq', 3)
```

Comment: this is an excellent solution, thank you, I never thought we can use contains also inside the selector, well, learned something...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the alias value later in the test, or in another test you could access it directly from the "Mocha context" by using a function callback

```js
if('tests the ag-grid', function() {    // now alias value is available on "this"

  cy.get('ag-grid-table  div.ag-row')
    .invoke('text')
    .then(text => text.match(/India/g).length)   // number of occurrences in table 
    .as("countrylength");

  cy.get('.flags').should('have.length', this.countrylength)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` command for this:

```js
cy.get('ag-grid-table div.ag-row')
  .filter(':contains("India")')
  .should('have.length', 3)
```

In case you want to use the length of different tests in your project you can use `Cypress.env()`. As aliases `as` are removed after every test.

```js
cy.get('ag-grid-table div.ag-row')
  .filter(':contains("India")')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    Cypress.env('length', len)
  })

//To use it in other test
cy.get('selector').type(Cypress.env('length'))
cy.get('selector').should('have.length', Cypress.env('length'))
```

Comment: thank you, also a good working solution, just updated to fit my case with .filter(':contains("India")').its('length').as("countrylength"); because I need to store the count and compare in later test step.